Serilog save properties into individual custom columns
I don't want to use Properties column for SQL Server, and want to have a single column with machine name and have its value in the table.
I tried below to retrieve machine name and other properties:
var machineName = new LoggerConfiguration().Enrich.WithMachineName().ToString();
var environmentUserName = new LoggerConfiguration().Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName().ToString();
var environmentName = new LoggerConfiguration().Enrich.WithEnvironmentName().ToString();
var threadID = new LoggerConfiguration().Enrich.WithThreadId().ToString();
var threadName = new LoggerConfiguration().Enrich.WithThreadName().ToString();
var processID = new LoggerConfiguration().Enrich.WithProcessId().ToString();
var processName = new LoggerConfiguration().Enrich.WithProcessName().ToString();

However, in database they are not coming right and even in variable:

Is there any possibility that I get them in variable and insert in to custom columns of my own?
